# Not working drop down validation

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to validate drop down but my code is not working.

View:

```
<tr>
  <td width="10%"><?php echo form_label('Countryt Name:', 'countryname'); ?></td>
  <td width="90%"><?php $country_namearray=array();
    $country_namearray[]="Select";
    foreach($country_name as $country){
    $country_namearray[$country['id']]=$country['country_name'];
    }
      echo form_dropdown('country_id', $country_namearray,@$statedata[0]->country_id,'class="input-small" id="country_id" required="required" title="The Country Name field is required." autofocus="autofocus"'); ?>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('country_id', 'Country Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
```

What is problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

i checked your code and it seems that you need to edit your select item with empty value.
for ex:

```
$country_namearray[''] = 'Please Select';
```

hope this will solve the validation problem. if you dont provide any value it will convert it as 0. thats why your validation code werent working